# Can't forward mail to gmail through hosting provider after 2fa configuration

Tags: email, gmail, forwarding, two-factor-authentication

I have multiple forwarding address on my hosting provider (1&1) that send to my personal email address on gmail (let's call it me@gmail.com). Right now it's setup as:

```
me@mydomain.com -> me@gmail.com
```

This previously worked and no longer does. The one major change I've made is the introduction of two-factor authentication to my gmail account. I've read through everything I can find on google authenticator and email forwarding, but I see no way to provide authorization to the gmail account. I also don't believe forwarding needs that.

How do I correct this configuration so I can continue to forward email to my gmail account?

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you are pulling in email from mydomain.com into your Gmail account? If so, I don't think App passwords are what you need.

Comment: You're reading it correct @Dimblefeck - I have a forwarding service configured for an email address, like `me@mydomain.com`, which is set to forward to Gmail. My hosting provider says this is working on their end, presumably showing successfully forwarded requests. It's not showing up in Gmail. Spam and deleted items have been checked. I'm getting nothing.

Comment: I thought as much, wanted to clarify for the sake of the App passwords suggestion. App passwords would be for operating the other way around. I'm sorry to say I can't offer any sage words of advice, but hey, at least I know my reading was right!

Comment: This appears to be expected behavior by Gmail. See [this](https://support.tigertech.net/gmail-discards-forwards). I'm forwarding to a different account now.